# What do these questions mean and how do I approach them?

Tags: testing, documentation

I am currently making documentations in regards to my finished product, however I do not understand what the question wants by asking for:

- Qualitative assessment of performance
- Quantitative assessment of performance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about _programming_, but about the definition of English words. A dictionary would be the proper resource to answer it.

Comment: please do, i dont think there's any need for voting to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A qualitative assessment of performance is a assessment which doesn't use specific measurements but compares the performance with the expectation or needs of the user. So something like:

> The performance of the import is low, but acceptable for the intended use.
>
> reaction of the application to user input most cases so fast, that no waiting time is perceived.

A quantitative assessment is based on measurements:

> The import processes 1 million records per hour
>
> 98% of all user interactions are processed withing 0.2 seconds

Also more detailed information like standard deviations or plotting a measure with regards to some variable, would be a quantitative assessment.

Note that both assessments are important. The quantitative is great for comparisons, for example if you want to compare the performance of two versions of an application.

The qualitative is what really matters. In the end it often doesn't matter how many millions or records you process per ms. The question is: Is the user satisfied, and in most cases the user doesn't base their feelings on some measurement, but on ... well ... their feelings.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Comment: When you think the answer was helpful you should upvote it. If it solved your problem you should accept it.